# Efficient and elegant way to fetch unique values from all columns - Big data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, unique

I have a dataframe with more than 600 columns. I have given a sample dataframe with few columns here

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'person_id' :[1,2,3],'obs_date':['12/31/2007','11/25/2009',np.nan],
   'hero_id':[2,4,np.nan],'date2':['12/31/2017',np.nan,'10/06/2015'],
   'heroine_id':[1,np.nan,5],'date3':['12/31/2027','11/25/2029',np.nan],
   'bud_source_value':[1250000,250000,np.nan],
   'prod__source_value':[10000,20000,np.nan]})
```

I would like to fetch the unique values from each column and output it in another dataframe

These are the two approaches that I tried

```
cols = df_new.columns.tolist()
unique_list = dict()
for c in cols:  #appraoch 1
    unique_list[c] = df_new[c].unique()
```

---

```
for c in cols:   #approach 2
    unique_list[c] = df_new[c].drop_duplicates()
```

Is there anyway to do this at one go without loop? Please note that **I expect to have unique values from each column and not unique row in dataframe**

As my data is over million records and columns are more than 600 any suggestions/solutions to improve would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
print({k:v.drop_duplicates().tolist() for k,v in df_new.items()})
```

Output:

```
{'bud_source_value': [1250000.0, 250000.0, nan], 'date2': ['12/31/2017', nan, '10/06/2015'], 'date3': ['12/31/2027', '11/25/2029', nan], 'hero_id': [2.0, 4.0, nan], 'heroine_id': [1.0, nan, 5.0], 'obs_date': ['12/31/2007', '11/25/2009', nan], 'person_id': [1, 2, 3], 'prod__source_value': [10000.0, 20000.0, nan]}
```

Comment: `df_new.items()` converts the df to a dict? Is that all?

Answer (score 1):

Convert dataframe into numpy array and do following

```
df_new =  np.array(df_new)
unique_list = np.unique(df_new,axis=1)
```

Numpy is much faster!

Comment: Numpy is fast, but pandas is too, since pandas depends on numpy, that's why `pd.Series.unique` gives a numpy array

Comment: but it gives an error `TypeError: The axis argument to unique is not supported for dtype object`

Comment: try unique_list = np.unique(df_new.astype("<U22"),axis=1)

Comment: It gives all the unique values in the dataframe but not column wise. the column names are missing